# Can the Drools rules configured in Optaplanner implement front-end custom configuration?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

At present, I have built a model and wrote the Drools rules in the configuration file. However, due to business characteristics, I need to constantly change the values involved in the Drools rules in the future use process. If you can only change it in the back-end file Convenient, I would like to ask whether it is possible to configure Drools rules on the front-end page and change the values in the rules flexibly?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer: no, not in practice**

Because writing constraints is coding (requires unit tests, etc). In practice, it's better to build out an arsenal of constraints and let the users pick the ones they want to use.

**Long answer: maybe**

There are various levels of adaptability:

1. Turn on/off constraints. Take a look at `@ConstraintConfiguration` etc in the docs. This works for ConstraintStreams and scoreDRL too. Constraints with ZERO weight have zero performance impact (for ConstraintStreams at least - not sure for score DRL any more).
2. Use configuring records, like a class `EmployeeAvailability`, that sets unavailability between a start and end datetime for one employee. This gives users the ability to block wednesday afternoons for Ann, saturday mornings for Beth and halloween evening for Carl.
3. Build a UI around ConstraintStreams and have end-users write their own constraints, just like in Excel. Only problem is that writing constraints is a very formal process that requires unit tests to be done correctly. The OptaPlanner team has been doing research around this, but it's far from trivial.

Business Central KIE Workbench has a Guided Rule Editor to compose scoreDRL by end-users. So in theory, it does 3). In practice, no users can use it.

For 3), you'll need a lot of funding. In practice, combining 1) and 2) does wonders to build out an arsenal of flexible constraints, so the users pick and chose the ones they need/Want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience, and I will consider your suggestions carefully.
I have another idea, whether it is possible to maintain the constraints by "using string splicing to describe constraints on the front end, and then translating the strings into Drools files and then identifying them by Optaplanner".